# Finding the real-symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors are known

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given that $(Λ, x) = \{1, (0,1,1)\} \cup \{2, (1,-1,1)\} \cup \{3, (-2,-1,1)\}$ are eigenpairs for the real symmetric matrix $A,$ how can I construct this matrix?

Comment: Do you understand that this means $$ A\left[ \begin{array}{r} -2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right] \left[ \begin{array}{r} -2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{array}\right] = 3\left[ \begin{array}{r} -2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{array}\right], $$ and similarly for the other eigenvectors? $\qquad$

Comment: Hint: $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ for some matrix $S$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes I understand it but in my lecture notes there is a shorter method rather than deriving equations of all individual a,b,c...g,h,i s by writing the equations for all eigenvalues, but I didn't understand it. It says A = Q.λ.(transpose of Q) where Q is the matrix constructed using the orthonormalized set of eigen vectors and lamda is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues 1,2,3. Why is it so?

Comment: @amd can you define the Λ and S in the equation  A=SΛS−1 you write?

Comment: $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. $S$ is for you to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $$D = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \\ \end{array} \right]$$

We are going to think of $D$ as the matrix of a linear operator $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ in regard to the matrix $\beta = \{ (0,1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}),(1/\sqrt{3},-1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3}),(-2/\sqrt{6},-1/\sqrt{6},1/\sqrt{6})\}$, whose elements are the normalized eigenvectors, so $\beta$ is orthonormal in the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is important, because the canonical basis $\alpha = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is also orthonormal, so the change of basis matrix is going to be orthogonal, so its inverse will be its transpose.

If $A$ is the matrix of $T$ in the canonical basis, we have that $$A = [I]_{\alpha}^{\beta} D [I]_{\beta}^{\alpha},$$ by the change of basis formula, where $[I]_{a}^{b}$ is the change of basis matrix from the basis $b$ to the basis $a$. If we call $P = [I]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$, then $$A = P D P^T,$$ since both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are orthonormal.

After we do these calculations, we'll find out that $$A = \frac{1}{3}\left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 8 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 5 & -2 \\ -1 & -2 & 5 \\ \end{array} \right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: symmetric matrices have orthogonal  Eigen vectors, check for orthogonality and try similar transformation.